# Are Lp norms equivalent on bounded functions with compact support?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Are Lp norms equivalent on certain space of functions? Here, functions are of course infinite dimensional.  I know that if functions are allowed to have singularity and be non-zero everywhere, then Lp norms are certainly not equivlent.

If functions have support and no singularity, will things change? If I have to go further, giving a strick upperbound to the functions would be enough right?

Answer (score 3):

If by equivalent you mean topologically equivalent, no. Consider $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [0,\epsilon] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ then $\| f \|_{L^\infty}=1$ but $\| f \|_{L^1}=\epsilon$ which can be arbitrarily small. The non-smoothness of this $f$ is not essential, either.

Comment: What if p is less than infinity?

Comment: $\|f\|_p = \epsilon^{1/p}$.  As $\epsilon \to 0+$, the ratio $\|f\|_p/\|f\|_q \to 0$ if $p < q$.

Comment: I think perhaps the only thing we can say in this case of bounded with compact domain, is if $f \in L^p$ then $f \in L^q$. Correct me in case i am wrong.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju There are basically two $L^p$ monotonicity theorems: if the space has finite measure then the lower spaces are contained in the higher ones, and if there is a nontrivial lower bound on the measure of any set with positive measure, then the higher spaces are contained in the lower ones. If neither of those hold (e.g. in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure) then you can have weird things, like functions in $L^p$ for exactly one $p$.